# ASIdentifierManager is not found in iOS12

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, ios12, idfa

I m writing here cos I'm really stuck and can't find an answer.

We have a small framework who can collect IDFA inside.
For IDFA collection first at all we checks `NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")`

The problem is:

Imagine we have a client and this client released version for iOS10-iOS12.
And this client gets IDFA for iOS10 and iOS11, but for all iOS12 there is no IDFA at all! After logs checked we have found that `NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")` is nil only for iOS12..

How the client could add a framework for iOS10, 11 but not for iOS12?

On the other hand, another client is doing well with iOS12.

Comment: Have you tried the `@import AdSupport;` or link against the framework in project?

Comment: We have `#include <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>`. And again - the same build works for iOS10, 11. But not for iOS12.
Looks like client somehow exclude linking exactly for iOS12 - but how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not answer your question completely, just text what I know and my guess.

**First**, the dynamic frameworks won't be loaded in your app process until you **use** it, such as the frameworks under the directory which are available in iOS with simulator device.

```
> cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
> # Now there are plenty of frameworks here.
> file  AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

How to **use** it? TLDR, call it with `[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager]` in your app anywhere, link against the framework firstly and compile it successfully, of course.

**Second**, what's the difference between using `NSClassFromString()` directly and calling `[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager]` anywhere?

For the former case, your application won't load the `AdSupport` framework bundle since there are not symbol named `ASIdentifierManager` in your executable program when the os kernel loads your program, it can be proved by print your app main bundle path and find the app executable file, try to `nm <path/to/executable_app> | grep "ASIdentifierManager"`, nothing will be found in result since you didn't *use* it.

For the latter one, try to grep the same symbol in the executable program, there it is.

> Note: it's not os kernel loads the frameworks by `nm` result list but the kernel loads the frameworks containing the symbols, check out more info about the dynamic loader [dyld](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dyld.3.html).

**Third**, `NSClassFromString` only checks the loaded classes, if the `AdSupport` framework doesn't be loaded, it returns nil without trying to load the framework containing the target class.

**Forth**, it's impossible to recall the difference between in iOS 10/11 and iOS 12 until you paste out more context about the IDFA and `AdSupport` framework usage in your project. Here is my one guess, some of the dependent libraries **use** the `AdSupport` framework in the early version but iOS 12, you have to try to dump the symbol list between in iOS 11 and iOS 12 and compare the result.

**Fifth**, I'm not sure what you want, maybe you're trying to avoid importing `AdSupport` framework explicitly, how about initializing a `NSBundle` by framework path and call the `-(BOOL)load` of `NSBundle` class, then you could get the `Class` object with `NSClassFromString`.

***UPDATE:***

```
NSString *strFrameworkPath = nil;

#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
strFrameworkPath = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH"];
#else
// Assume that the AdSupport and Foundation framework are in the same directory.
strFrameworkPath = [NSBundle bundleForClass:NSPredicate.class].bundlePath;
strFrameworkPath = [strFrameworkPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
#endif

strFrameworkPath = [strFrameworkPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AdSupport.framework"];
NSAssert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strFrameworkPath], @"Invalid framework bundle path!");

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:strFrameworkPath];

if (!bundle.isLoaded) {
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![bundle loadAndReturnError:&error]) {
        DDLogError(@"Load framework bundle %@ with error %@", bundle, error);
    }
}

DDLogDebug(@"bundle: %@", bundle.bundlePath);
DDLogDebug(@"class: %@", NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager"));
```

You may need to enhance the compatibility of kinds of the device for products, for more details about the `NSBundle` usage, check out [the official documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html).

Comment: Man, thank you so much for this answer! I really appreciate it.
Could you point the sample code with `NSBundle` and `-(BOOL)load`?

Comment: NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework"];
    BOOL success = [b load];

Comment: Updated, you may need to enhance the compatibility of kinds of the device for products.